# JBoss5 CLIENT-CERT authentication getting HTTP Status 401 - Cannot authenticate with the provided credentials error

Tags: java, authorization, jboss5.x, restful-authentication

I want mutual authentication using CLIENT-CERT and also specify role with Restful Jersey web service.
Here clientAuth="false" in server.xml

My web.xml is as follow:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
     </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
       <param-value>com.aditi.test</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<login-config>
    **<auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>**
    <realm-name>JMX Console</realm-name>
</login-config> 
<security-role>
<description>Admin role</description>
<role-name>admin</role-name>        
</security-role>
```

My jboss-web.xml is:

```
<jboss-web>
<security-domain>java:/jaas/client_cert</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

Also I have created server.keystore, server.truststore, client.keystore, client.truststore and client.p12 using keytool and openssl.

Changes in login-config.xml is:

```
<application-policy name="client_cert">
<authentication>
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag="required">
    <module-option name="usersProperties">
     props/cert-users.properties</module-option>
    <module-option name="rolesProperties">
      props/cert-roles.properties</module-option>
    <module-option name="verifier">
     com.secure.CertVerifier</module-option>
  </login-module>
</authentication>
```

And jboss-service.xml contains:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.security.plugins.JaasSecurityDomain" name="jboss.security:service=SecurityDomain">
<constructor>
    <arg type="java.lang.String" value="client_cert"/>
</constructor>
<attribute name="KeyStoreURL">${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/server.keystore</attribute>
<attribute name="KeyStorePass">base123</attribute>
<attribute name="TrustStoreURL">${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/server.truststore</attribute>
<attribute name="TrustStorePass">base123</attribute>
<depends>jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityManager</depends>
```

and com.secure.CertVerifier is:

```
public class CertVerifier implements X509CertificateVerifier {
@Override
public boolean verify(X509Certificate xcert, String arg1, KeyStore arg2,
        KeyStore arg3) {
    System.out.println("hi verify");
    Principal pr=xcert.getSubjectDN();
    System.out.println("hi dear "+pr.getName());
    return true;
}}
```

also cert-users.properties file is empty.
and cert-roles.properties file is:

CN\=ClientHost,\ OU\=test,\ O\=test,\ L\=pune,\ ST\=mah,\ C=IN=admin

Now If i access RESTful web service through browser i want to import client.p12 certificate and after that i will getting error like

```
HTTP Status 401 - Cannot authenticate with the provided credentials
```

How I resolve it? I want to authentication as well as authorization using CLIENT-CERT in Jboss5. What is going wrong here? How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

xml is

```
<display-name>Hello</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
<param-value>com.aditi.test</param-value>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
<param-value>com.aditi.test</param-value>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/hello/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>     
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

jboss-web.xml is

```
<jboss-web>
<security-domain>java:/jaas/simple-security-domain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml is

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 

       port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"

       scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol = "TLS" 

   securityDomain="java:/jaas/simple-security-domain"

       SSLImplementation="org.jboss.net.ssl.JbossImplementation"/>
```

Create certificates as follows:

## Create the server and application client key stores and certificates

keytool -genkeypair -alias serverkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=Server,OU=Application Development,O=Home,L=Auckland,S=AK,C=NZ" -keypass password -storepass password -keystore server.keystore
keytool -genkeypair -alias clientkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=Client,OU=Application Development,O=Home,L=Auckland,S=AK,C=NZ" -keypass password -storepass password -keystore client.keystore

## Copy the client's public certificate to the server's keystore

keytool -exportcert -keystore client.keystore -storepass password -file client-public.cer -alias clientkey
keytool -importcert -keystore server.keystore -storepass password -file client-public.cer -alias clientcert -noprompt

## Take a peek at the server's keystore to make sure that the client's certificate is there

keytool -v -list -keystore server.keystore -storepass password

## Copy the server's public certificate to the client's keystore

keytool -exportcert -keystore server.keystore -storepass password -file server-public.cer -alias serverkey
keytool -importcert -keystore client.keystore -storepass password -file server-public.cer -alias servercert -noprompt

## Take a peek at the client's keystore to make sure that the client's certificate is there

keytool -v -list -keystore client.keystore -storepass password

## Create a browser keystore most browsers can read easily

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.keystore -srcstorepass password -srcalias clientkey -destkeystore client.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass password -destalias clientkey -noprompt

## Take a peek at the browser's keystore to make sure that the client's certificate is there

keytool -v -list -keystore client.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass password

## Copy server.keystore file into ${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/conf folder.

Create jboss-service.xml file in deploy/ folder as follow:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.security.plugins.JaasSecurityDomain" name="jboss.security:service=PBESecurityDomain">

<constructor>
```

```
<attribute name="KeyStoreURL">resource:server.keystore</attribute>
<attribute name="KeyStorePass">
{CLASS}org.jboss.security.plugins.FilePassword:${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/server.password</attribute>
<attribute name="TrustStoreURL">resource:server.keystore</attribute>
<attribute name="TrustStorePass">  {CLASS}org.jboss.security.plugins.FilePassword:${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/server.password</attribute>
<attribute name="Salt">welcometojboss</attribute>
<attribute name="IterationCount">15</attribute>
</mbean>
```

Here I have create encrypted password file server.password
Execute following command

java -classpath $JBOSS_HOME /common/lib/jbosssx.jar org.jboss.security.plugins.FilePassword welcometojboss 13 your-pass server.password

This command uses jbosssx.jar as the classpath (-cp) and the FilePassword security plug-in to create a keystore.password file with the password set as unit-tests-server. To verify you have permission to create a keystore.password file, you supply the salt and iteration parameters configured in the

The Salt and IterationCount are the variables that define the strength of your encrypted password, so you can vary it from what is shown. Ensure you record the new values, and use when generating the encrypted password.

It required jbosssx.jar which may located in ${jboss_home}/common/lib folder.
Copy server.password file into ${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/conf folder.

[Kindly Refer the given link to know more security concepts in Jboss5](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/pdf/Security_Guide/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform-5-Security_Guide-en-US.pdf)

Update the Tomcat service Mbean

Navigate to $JBOSS_HOME/server/$PROFILE/deploy/jbossweb.sar/META-INF/. Open jboss-beans.xml and append the following  tag to the WebServer end of the file. Adding the  tag specifies that tomcat must start after jboss.security:service=PBESecurityDomain

```
<bean name="WebServer"
....
class="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatService">
<depends>jboss.security:service=PBESecurityDomain</depends>
```

Deployment of web service and accessing from client
Create xyz.war which contains web service and deployed in ${JBOS_HOME}/server/default/deploy/ folder.

Import client.p12 certificate in browser.
In Mozilla Go to Preferences --> View Certificate --> click on import --> select client.p12 --> enter password Then Ok

[image: Import client.p12 certificate on client browser]

Open browser and type following url:
http://yourwebservicehost:8080/Hello/rest/hello/Test
Getting below window which is cilent certificate then click on ok
[image: Display after accessing web service]